# How can I dump a list of variables to a file when a server is killed?

Tags: java, server, client

I'm in the middle of developing a server and client in java. Each client can send and retrieve messages that are stored in a list of JSON objects. I'm wondering if there is a way that I can dump this list to a file when the server is killed, so that way if the server is crashes or the process is killed, the messages can be recovered when the server starts back up again?

I'm unsure as to whether this is possible and I'm wondering if a better alternative would be to periodically save the data to a file constantly that way it would be kept up to date, but surely this would be more resource intensive?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) or [AWS SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/).